# Angular show error message and invalid class on form submit

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form (Template driven from) on Angular(5) and I'm trying to show the error messages and class on the inputs when they are invalid when the user try to submit the form.

Currently I'm able to do this, but only if the user interacts with the form. This is my code so far:

```
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
    border-color: $color-error;
}

this.myForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(FormPattern.name)
    ])
}, {updateOn: 'submit'});

<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" />

        <div class="form_error" *ngIf="myForm.controls.name.touched && myForm.controls.name.errors">
            <small *ngIf="myForm.controls.name.errors.required">Required field</small>
            <small *ngIf="myForm.controls.name.errors.pattern">Invalid name</small>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, on submit doesn't change any property on the form, also, I didn't found a property like `submited` like there is the properties `touched: true|false` and `untouched: true|false`.

I'm already using the new option `{updateOn: 'submit'}` but I didn't found a way to identy if the form was submited. Also the properties `dirty` and `pristine` remain as if the form had no interactions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show an error message if the form is invalid you can show it by using

```
<small *ngIf="!myForm.valid">Form is Invalid</small>
```

And If you want to check the form is valid or not on submit you can do it by this (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.valid)"
and in component

```
 onSubmit(valid)
    {
        if(valid==true){
             Form is valid
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show validation messages before submitting, you can use:

```
<form #contactForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="contactForm.valid && sendMessage()">

    <input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="formData.email" #email="ngModel" required email>

    <div *ngIf="contactForm.submitted && email.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="email.errors?.required">
            Please fill in the required fields.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="email.errors?.email">
            Please enter a valid email address.
        </div>
    </div>

    ...
</form>
```